# Exceptions! Console Calculator (Java)

Tags: java

I'm still quite new at this, I'm getting the following error:
exceptionA.methodA(name);
          ^ cannot find symbol

Heres the code I have so far,many thanks in advance!:

```
class testing{

    public static void main(String[] args){
    String name = args[0];
    exceptions exceptionA = new exceptions();   

    try{
        exceptionA.methodA(name);
    }
    catch(exceptionA e){
            System.out.print("Please enter your name!!");
    }
    finally{
            System.out.println(".");
    }
    }


    void methodA(String name) throws exceptionA{
        if (name == ""){
            throw new exceptionA();
    }
    else{
        System.out.println("Welcome " + name + "!");
        System.out.println("Please select from the following options: " + "\n" + "\n" + "1.Addition - Type ADD" + "\n" + 
                           "2.Subtraction - Type SUB" + "\n" + "3.Multiplication - Type MULT" + "\n" + "4.Division - Type DIV" + "\n" + "5.Hexidecimal - Type HEX" + "\n" + "6.Octal - Type OCT" +  "\n" + "7.Decimal - Type DECI" + "\n" + "8. Square Root - Type SQR" + "\n" + "9. Power - Type PWR" + "\n" + "10.Sin - Type SIN" + "\n" + "11.Cos - Type COS" + "\n" + "12.Tan -Type TAN");
    }


}
}


class exceptionA extends Exception{}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is just wrong.

```
exceptionA.methodA(name);
```

I think you want this.

```
new testing().methodA(name);
```

And you should really follow Java capitalization conventions. That is `Testing` and `Exception`.

Answer (score 0):

Just a first glance: You are writing this:

```
exceptions exceptionA = new exceptions();
```

In Java, when you declare a variable, the right order is this: `Type_or_Class varName`.

There's no `exceptions` class; your class name is `exceptionA`. So the right way to write this is:

```
exceptionA exceptions = new exceptionA();
```

And Elliot Frisch is right: follow Java capitalization conventions.

Take a look to the [Java Tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/)

Answer (score 0):

`exceptionA` seems to be your custom exception. Why you  are calling your exception class for `methodA`. That method is in your `testing` class.

This is enough

```
 try{
   new testing().methodA(name);
 }catch(exceptionA e){


 }
```

In addition you should use proper Java naming convention here. Class name should start with Uppercase letter and method should start with lowercase letter.